# How to use the bootstrap grid to center a div on a full screen background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a full screen background image and i would like to use the bootstrap grid to center a div on the page without interacting with the background.

This is the HTML i have:

```css
    .full{
        background: url('http://whd.erth.biz/wp-content/uploads/mixed2/office-relax-clean-ping-pong-1920x1080.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index:-10;
    }
    .frameHolder {
        margin-top:5%;
        height:500px;
        position:absolute;
    }
    
    .quizFrame{
        position:absolute;
        height:500px;
        width:100%;
    }
    
    .quizFrame1{
        background-color:white;
        z-index:10;
    
    }
```

```html
<html class = "full" lang="en">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
         </head>
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
            <div class = "col-md-6 frameHolder">
                <div id="frame1" class = "quizFrame quizFrame1">
                    <p>Click Start Game below to begin the quiz</p>
                    <button onclick="Run();">Start Game</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </html>
```

No matter what positioning i apply to frameholder/quizFrame (relative/absolute), i always end up with the content not centered. However without the background image everything works fine.

How can i properly center my div and position elements using the grid without any interaction to the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had errors in your code. You do not apply styles to the HTML tag. You use the body tag to apply styles to your pages. This should work for you now. I have marked my changes made.

```css
body{ /* Changed the tag */
    background: url('http://whd.erth.biz/wp-content/uploads/mixed2/office-relax-clean-ping-pong-1920x1080.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index:-10;
}
.frameHolder {
    margin-top:5%;
    height:500px;
    position:absolute;
}

.quizFrame{
    position:absolute;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}

.quizFrame1{
    background-color:white;
    z-index:10;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en"> <!-- CAHNGE -->
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
     </head>
 <div class="container"> <!-- CAHNGE -->
  <div class = "row">
   <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
   <div class = "col-md-6 frameHolder">
    <div id="frame1" class = "quizFrame quizFrame1">
     <p>Click Start Game below to begin the quiz</p>
     <button onclick="Run();">Start Game</button>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
 </div> <!-- CAHNGE -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-4 offset-col-md4 text-center"></div>
```

Centered Column, with centered content, it's as simple as that.